# How to dynamically disable a filter inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

It is possible to remove filter using a checkbox?

If checkboxes are checked, filters inside ng-repeat would be disabled. For example, if the checkboxes **countryfilter** and **winetypefilter** are checked, the related filters would be disabled.

Original code (filters enabled)

```
<li ng-repeat="wine in wines | winetypefilter:winetypes| countryfilter:countrytypes | stylefilter:styletypes">
                {{wine.name}} is a {{wine.type}} with {{wine.style}} style from {{wine.country}}
</li>
```

(filters disabled with the checkboxes, **countryfilter** and **winetypefilter** )
Would result:

```
<li ng-repeat="wine in wines | stylefilter:styletypes">
            {{wine.name}} is a {{wine.type}} with {{wine.style}} style from {{wine.country}}
</li>
```

Comment: i think you will have to write your own custom filter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

of course you can enable disable your filter dynamically... there can be many ways to do it simplest solution that comes to my mind is just sending third parameters as a boolean to check if filter is enable or not...

here is filter sample...

```
app.filter('winetypefilter', function () {
  return function(input, filter, isEnable) {
    // if isEnable then filter out wines
    if (isEnable) {
      var result = [];
      angular.forEach(input, function (wine) {
          angular.forEach(filter, function (isfiltered, type) {
              if (isfiltered && type === wine.type) {
                  result.push(wine);
              }
          });
      });
      return result;
    } 
    // otherwise just do not any filter just send input without changes
    else{
      return input
    }
  };
});
```

and here is [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/0TtOrBb6wxaMJ7nWGY7u?p=preview)...

Comment: Thanks for this, my case was little complex, where I had different filters depending one on another, but this answer helped me find the way to accomplish what I need it...