# Applying Angular ng-repeat filter on condition

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and I wanted to to know how to apply and remove a filter in ng-repeat directive but I want to remove or add the filter on some condition such as on URL change using $stateParams

```
if($stateParams.x){
  //remove unique filter
}
else{
   //add unique filter
}
```

below is the code that I am working on

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl as item">
<div >
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | unique: 'column'" myfilter>
    {{ item.column }}
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

here is a plunker link that I am trying to do this but it is not working.
http://plnkr.co/edit/zwy7slwOPfvLqJPVV1sk?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done if you pass in additional param in unique filter with some flag to enable and disable unique filter. In other words if flag is true then you will go with the unique logic other wise you will just return all items. It has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110189/how-to-dynamically-disable-a-filter-inside-ng-repeat) along with a plunker sample

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write your own filter you can have an outer ng-if like this:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl as item">
<div>
  <ul ng-if="$stateParams.x">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | unique: 'column'" myfilter>
      {{ item.column }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul ng-if="!$stateParams.x>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{ item.column }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```